# blank page when trying to change upload directory

Tags: php, wordpress, path, directory, attachment

Working with wordpress 4.2.2, when I use this code in child theme function.php to change the attachments upload directory according to each post type :

```
function wpse_16722_type_upload_dir( $args ) {
// Get the current post_id
$id = ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : '' );
if( $id ) {    
   // Set the new path depends on current post_type
   $newdir = '/' . get_post_type( $id );
   $args['path']    = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['path'] ); //remove default subdir
   $args['url']     = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['url'] );      
   $args['subdir']  = $newdir;
   $args['path']   .= $newdir; 
   $args['url']    .= $newdir; 
   return $args;
   }
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_16722_type_upload_dir' );
```

I get a blank page!!
there is no empty rows in the function.php and the problem appears only after adding this code. I really need it to organize my upload folder, but without a blank page.
is there any solution?

Comment: blank page means syntax errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: nothing happened, nothing is displayed, blank page

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above, you need to see the error reporting.  Add to the top of wp-config.php:
`php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

If that's not working, find `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and set the value to `true`

This might also help, add to the top of wp-config to pipe errors to err.log at your document root:

`@ini_set( 'log_errors', 'On' );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 'Off' );
@ini_set( 'error_log', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/err.log' );`